# Sorting values along axis=1 with NaNs at the start of row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, dataframe

How to sort the pandas dataframe sort all the column values in a row in ascending order and keep the NaN values at first

Example Data Frame is

```
                       2018-07-01  2018-07-02  2018-07-03  2018-07-04  
cell_name                                                                                                                                            
1002_NUc_Marathalli_7        0.734       0.550       NaN         0.481             
1002_NUc_Marathalli_8        1.338       1.220       0.911       0.601       
1002_NUc_Marathalli_9        0.330       1.180       0.754       0.631       
1003_IU2_Munnekolalu_7       0.628       0.479       0.988       0.694       
1003_IU2_Munnekolalu_8       5.327       6.831       8.387       9.428
```

The output should be in

```
1002_NUc_Marathalli_7 NaN 0.481 0.550 0.734
```

I can create another dataframe using:

`df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values,axis=1), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)`

But here the `nan` values are coming at the end of the row. I want the `nan` values at the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the dataframe rows using a `key` argument to keep `NaNs` first:

```
l = df.apply(sorted, key = lambda s: (~np.isnan(s), s), axis = 1)
pd.DataFrame(l.values.tolist(), columns=df.columns)

      2018-07-01  2018-07-02  2018-07-03  2018-07-04
0         NaN       0.481       0.550       0.734
1       0.601       0.911       1.220       1.338
2       0.330       0.631       0.754       1.180
3       0.479       0.628       0.694       0.988
4       5.327       6.831       8.387       9.428
```

**Explanation**

To see the way `sorted` is working in this case, lets take for example:

```
l = [0.734, 0.481, np.nan, 0.550]
```

Sorted accepts a `key` argument, which can be used to define a function with which the data collection can be transformed before the actual sorting takes place.

So what would make sense in this case? Ideally  to have some criteria under which we can identify if there is a `np.nan` in the sequence, and make those cases come first. How can the data be transformed so that later on `sorted` can achieve this?

What can be done is add an additional field, for each item in the list, that will also be taken into account to sort the list. Say we instead have:

```
lt = [(1, 0.734), (1, 0.481), (0, np.nan), (1, 0.550)]
```

So essentially an identifier of whether on not each element is a `NaN`. Now when we do:

```
sorted(lt)
[(0, nan), (1, 0.481), (1, 0.55), (1, 0.734)]
```

What `sorted` has done hear is to sort using both items in each `tuple`, so prioritising the first element (hence tuples starting with a `0` come first), and for the rest it sorted by the second term as the first is `1`. So what could be a way to achieve so?

If the `lambda` expression above is rewritten as a list comprehension, it would be equivalent to:

```
sl = [(~np.isnan(s), s) for s in l]
print(sl)
[(True, 0.734), (True, 0.481), (False, nan), (True, 0.55)]
```

Note that tese boolean values are enough, as they are interpreted as `True==1` and `False==0`, which will give the desired order in this case. If we do:

```
sorted(sl)
[(False, nan), (True, 0.481), (True, 0.55), (True, 0.734)].
```

This can be implemented in the `key` argument as a `lambda` or anonymous function, as:

```
sorted(l, key = lambda s: (~np.isnan(s), s))
```

Which for the example above, would give:

```
[nan, 0.481, 0.55, 0.734]
```

Comment: Updated with a detailed explanation @srimannarayana , hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fillna(float('-inf'))` and `replace`:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.sort(df.fillna(float('-inf')).values, axis=1), 
    index=df.index, 
    columns=df.columns
).replace(float('-inf'), np.nan)
```

Comment: perhaps `float('-inf')` is a better choice than `0`